# The everyday spear

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

> This is the everyday spear, beware!
>   It hurts and draws blood if not handled with care.
>   It dips below flowing planes, jumps back up before long,
>   Repairs old and creates new, if one knows how it's done.
>   It's shiny and smooth, but unbending and hard,
>   in it's tail there's a hole as an integral part.

What is this everyday spear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be

> a needle.

This is the everyday spear, beware!

> It's a household object, and  pointy like a spear.

It hurts and draws blood if not handled with care.

> You can hurt yourself with it if you're not careful.

It dips below flowing planes, jumps back up before long,

> A needle goes through fabric and then comes back.

Repairs old and creates new, if one knows how it's done.

> A needle can be used to fix broken clothes or make something new.

It's shiny and smooth, but unbending and hard,
in it's tail there's a hole as an integral part.

> Check and check.

Comment: 55 seconds, ouch!

Comment: @Stiv Hehe, I did have a feeling someone else was typing at the same time!

Comment: Have you ever used one? They do bend. Just saying.  :-)

Comment: @computercarguy As it happens, I have!

Answer (score 6):

This is a:

> **NEEDLE** (of the type used for sewing)

*This is the everyday spear, beware!*
*It hurts and draws blood if not handled with care.*

> A sewing needle is long, pointed and can be sharp (like a spear). You might accidentally prick your finger and draw blood if you aren't careful.

*It dips below flowing planes, jumps back up before long,*

> This describes a typical sewing motion, moving the needle up and down through a sheet of material (a 'flowing plane').

*Repairs old and creates new, if one knows how it's done.*

> You use a sewing needle to repair old garments, and with a little expertise you can even create whole new items to wear!

*It's shiny and smooth, but unbending and hard,*
*in it's tail there's a hole as an integral part.*

> Typically a sewing needle is made of metal - shiny, smooth, unbending and hard - and at the opposite end to the point there's a hole (the eye) to put the thread through...